# Convert an image file into a shape file

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, polygon

I have a high resolution layout of a floor (in a building) which I would like convert to a shapefile or polygons. The image is a JPEG, it outlines the walls of the rooms and the locations of beds in the on the floor. I would like to convert that JPEG image into a shapefile, or polygon, so that I can overlay a predictive model onto it.

I have done this with simpler shapes. For example, using the geom_polygon tutorial (http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_polygon.html) so I know it can be done. But the layout is more complex and if I can I would like to overlay posterior probabilities of my predictive model overtop of the true ward layout. Right now, this involves me mapping out the co-ordinates of the wall intersections and create polygons that way (doable, but it takes a long time).

It would be ideal to convert the room layout into a shape file, and load that into R instead (once I have the shape file, I've converted it to a polygon to use in ggplot, so that isn't the issue).

Here is an example of what my layout data looks like 
[image: Example of layout]
The thicker lines represent walls and the small rectangles are beds.  What I want is to input this into R and that the points line up to a cartesian co-ordinate system, it would also be good to get the bed co-ordinates as well. I don't have access to ARCGis..or any geographers...

Comment: This may be possibe with `R`, but my guess it would be quicker and simpler to download and install the free and open source [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), and digitise your image with that GIS program to get a shapefile. There are several detailed tutorials on doing this in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you - I will give that a try and see what I can do.